# Assign mongo selectors in find() dynamically

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-helper

I have the following problem: I have an interface where a user can filter stuff out based on several inputs. There are 5 inputs. When an input is filled out I want to add it's value to the helper returning the collection. The problem I can't solve is how to do this dynamically. Sometimes the user might fill out one input, sometimes three, sometimes all 5. Within the find() method you can only write down meteor's syntax:

```
mongoSelector: fieldName,
```

This means you can only hardcode stuff within find(). But just adding all 5 selectors doesn't work, since if one of the values is empty, the find searches for an empty string instead of nothing.

I thought of doing conditionals or variables but both don't work within find because of the required syntax. What could I do to solve this?

```javascript
var visitorName;
var visitorAge;
Session.set('visitorName', visitorName);
Session.set('visitorAge', visitorAgee);


Template.web.helpers({
    visitors: function() {
        return Visitors.find({ visitor_name: Session.get('visitorName'), visitor_age: Session.get('visitorAge') });
    }
});


Template.web.events({
  "change #visitor_name": function (event, template) {
    visitorName = $(event.currentTarget).val();
  }
});



Template.web.events({
  "click #reset_filter": function (event, template) {
    return Visitors.find();
    $(input).val('');    
  }
});
```

Comment: This is probably best answered with a complete example. What are the input types (text, select, etc.)? When should the find update (submit, keyup, change)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4zmt71py/

Here's an example. In the example it's hardcoded and only works when all 3 inputs are defined. What I need to achieve is set the find() depending on how many inputs are defined. Eventually I wanna reset it again with a button click. 

One option would be for example check if a session is defined and if not, don't include the corresponding part. But this like anything else I've thought of doesn't work because of the syntax limitation.

If condition:
return Visitors.find({ 
if (Session.get('visitorName') != undefined) {visitor_name: Session.get('visitorName')}
})

Comment: @AndreasGalster Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/m5qxoh3b/

This one works

```
Template.web.helpers({
    visitors: function() {
        var query = {};

        var visitorName = (Session.get('visitorName') || "").trim();
        if (visitorName) {
            query["visitor_name"] = visitorName;
        }
        //same thing for other fields

        return Visitors.find(query);            
    }
});



Template.web.events({
  "change #visitor_name": function (event, template) {
      var visitorName = $(event.currentTarget).val();
      Session.set('visitorName', visitorName);
  }
});
```